# Как получить ссылку из баннера?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, chrome-extension

Необходимо получить ссылки из баннеров на сайте посредством JavaScript в браузере Chrome.
[image: Пример страницы где размещены баннеры]

Как пример взял сайт speedtest.net, где размещены баннеры: как видно на скриншоте — Chrome может видеть ссылки баннера, но как самому достичь этого средствами JavaScript?

Comment: Пожалуйста старайтесь писать грамотно:
- не силён, - посредством, - запятая ставится вплотную к предыдущему слову а после неё ставится пробел. Уточните суть вопроса: вы хотите добыть ссылку на странице своего сайта или вам нужен некий букмарклет для обработки произвольной страницы?

Answer (score 3):

Если я Вас правильно понял - следует использовать специальное расширение для Chrome: [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=ru). Данное расширение позволяет запускать Ваши скрипты на необходимых страницах/доменах и т.д.

Что касается самого когда скрипта:

Если использовать чистый JS:

```
// Сохраняем в переменную узел с нашим баннером, узнав его по id
var someDOMElement = document.getElementById('aw0');
// А так мы можем взять любой атрибут, например href
var hrefOfelement = someDOMElement.getAttribute('href');
// Можно всё делать в одну строку
var hrefOfelement = document.getElementById('aw0').getAttribute('href');
```

[Можно получить элементы и по другим атрибутам](http://javascript.ru/tutorial/dom/search)

Что касается именно Вашей задачи - алгоритм следующий:
1) Собираете все необходимые Вам DOM элементы, например, в массив (в JS это объекты);
2) В цикле проходимся по каждому из них

Answer (score 2):

Со страницы добраться до элементов внутри ifram'а другого домена невозможно, если только хром не запущен с флагом `--disable-web-security`.

Answer (score 2):

Баннерная реклама обычно создается на основе фреймов, где во фрейме находящимся на странице вашего сайта открывается страница на чужом домене (домене рекламной площадки).

Из-за политики безопасности браузера нельзя получить содержимое фрейма находящегося на другом домене.